# How to use addEventListener and postMessage in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I've got an issue with addEventListener and postMessage. 
I have dialog window to sign in and there I have a button to sign in with Facebook. When user clicks to this button will open window to log in with Facebook. Then user submits Facebook form and page will be redirected to my static HTML page which forwards some info using postMessage. I have addEventListener and handleMessage method which must handle all messages that send from static HTML page but handleMessage method works many times, this method handle messages which I don't send by using postMessage.

Sign in component:

```
constructor(public thisDialogRef: MatDialogRef<SigninComponent>, private auth: AuthService,
    private userService: UserService, private router: Router,
    private  alertwindow: AlertWindowsComponent) {
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener("message", this.handleMessage.bind(this), false);
    }
    else {
      (<any>window).attachEvent("onmessage", this.handleMessage.bind(this));
    }
}

launchFbLogin() {
    this.authWindow = window.open(`https://www.facebook.com/v3.2/dialog/oauth?&response_type=token&display=popup&client_id=318651702058203&display=popup&redirect_uri=${this.url}facebook-auth.html&scope=email`,null,'width=600,height=400,top=400,left=400'); 
}
handleMessage(event: Event) {
    const message = event as MessageEvent;
    ...
}
```

Applying method postMessage in a static HTML file:

```
window.opener.postMessage(JSON.stringify(message), "http://localhost:4200");
```

Comment: While this doesn't answer your question, I've successfully used the facebook javascript sdk to sign in folks to an angular app. The SDK's [`FB.login()`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/examples#login) method allows you to sign someone in and receive the authentication object without leaving the current page / angular app (so you won't need to deal with `postMessage()`.

Comment: What is not working here? Can you clarify your issue here?

Comment: @wannadream Sign in component handle messages from unknown sources and handleMessage method run many times but need to run only one time when I'm using postMessage in static Html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this helps solving your problem. Based on the logic you sent in comment, you will need to add a flag in your code which checks the state of your handler in order to avoid duplicate calls.

```
handlerState = 0; // 0 - Not started, 1 - Being processed, 2 - Processed

constructor(public thisDialogRef: MatDialogRef<SigninComponent>, private auth: AuthService,
    private userService: UserService, private router: Router,
    private  alertwindow: AlertWindowsComponent) {
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener("message", this.handleMessage.bind(this), false);
    }
    else {
      (<any>window).attachEvent("onmessage", this.handleMessage.bind(this));
    }
}

launchFbLogin() {
    this.authWindow = window.open(`https://www.facebook.com/v3.2/dialog/oauth?&response_type=token&display=popup&client_id=318651702058203&display=popup&redirect_uri=${this.url}facebook-auth.html&scope=email`,null,'width=600,height=400,top=400,left=400'); 
}
handleMessage(event: Event) {

    if (handlerState != 0) {
        return; // Already being processe or processed already.
    }

    handlerState = 1;

    const message = event as MessageEvent;
    ...

    handlerState = 2;
}
```